# How to retrieve attachments from child pages of a specific Page in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How would I retrieve attachments from all **subpages** of a specific Page ID?

Example:

SPECIFIC PAGE

- Child (with attachments)
- Child (with attachments)
- Child (with attachments)

I'm currently using this code to retrieve all attachments site-wide, however I would like to limit this to only pull images from all children of a specific Page.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
        the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
?>
```

Almost there using this code as per Nick's suggestion below:

```
<?php

$mypages = get_pages('child_of=19');
foreach ( $mypages as $mypage  ) {
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => $mypage->ID, 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'rand'));


if ($attachments) {

    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {

        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
        the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
}
?>
```

However, there are two remaining issues:

1. Limiting the amount of **total photos** pulled.  Using 'numberposts' only limits the amount of images pulled from each post
2. Randomization.   Orderby => rand only randomizes the images within each post.  I would like to randomly shuffle the order for everything.

Comment: Just in case I'd recommend you to move this question to the WordPress site, over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `get_pages( $args )`

```
<?php $args = array(
'child_of' => 'SPECIFIC PAGE',
'parent' => 'SPECIFIC PAGE',
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'numberposts' => -1
); ?>
```

Using `child_of` will get all children and grandchildren.

`parent` will limit this to just the children that have this as a parent.  No grandchildren.

See here for more details. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: @Joe, you could store all of the attachment data in a multidimensional array and [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it.  Then use a `for` loop to display the proper number of attachments.

Comment: just curious- wouldn't this still be pulling extra unused data (say there are 1,000 images for example)?  I'd assume that is a lot of wasted work being done for the server?

Comment: You've already pulled the data from the database in the `get_children()` call.  Now you just need to operate on it.  Instead of outputting it in the foreach loop, store it in the array.  Then shuffle the array, Then loop through the array to output what you want.  Yes, it is a little more work, but I can't think of a way to get what you want from the `get_children()` or `get_pages()` calls.